# Insert spaces around words between parentheses

Tags: bash, unix, awk, gsub

I have a file called `sso-shop-med.txt`.

```
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by)values('204026601',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by)values('502689031',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by)values('502683504',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009239', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009292', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704');
```

I want to add a gap between `)values(` like follows: `) values (`

I have written the following `awk` command but it's not working

```
awk '{gsub(/")values("/, ") values (" ); print}' sso-shop-med.txt
```

Resulting error:

```
awk: syntax error in regular expression ")values(" at values("
 source line number 1
 context is
    {gsub(/")values("/, ") values (" >>>  ) <<<
```

Comment: I'm curious - what do you think `/")values("/` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your version of awk, but this appears to work:

```
awk '{gsub("\\)values\\(", "\) values \(") ; print}'
```

turns

```
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by)values('204026601',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409');
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by)values('502689031',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409');
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by)values('502683504',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409');
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009239', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704');
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009292', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704');
```

into:

```
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204026601',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409');
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409');
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502683504',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409');
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009239', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704');
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009292', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704');
```

How does that look?

Comment: This is actually the wrong answer since it's using a string in a regexp context and so forcing awk to have to parse that string twice (once to convert it into a regexp) which is why you need 2 escapes in this answer but only 1 in [the other (correct) awk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44206604/1745001). You also don't need to escape parens at all in a replacement string,

Answer (score 1):

In the regex you need to escape the parens and get rid of the quotes:

```
$ cat file
last_updated_by)values('204026601',
last_updated_by)values('502689031',
last_updated_by)values('502683504',
last_updated_by) values ('204009239',
last_updated_by) values ('204009292',

$ awk '{gsub(/\)values\(/, ") values (" ); print}' file
last_updated_by) values ('204026601',
last_updated_by) values ('502689031',
last_updated_by) values ('502683504',
last_updated_by) values ('204009239',
last_updated_by) values ('204009292',
```

Answer (score 0):

***gawk*** approach:

```
awk '{ gsub(/ *values */," values ",$0) }1' sso-shop-med.txt
```

The output:

```
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204026601',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502683504',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009239', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009292', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704');
```

---

- `gsub(/ *values */," values ",$0)` - replace/***rearrange*** `values` word with leading/trailing whitespace (If there were redundant spaces around `values` - they will be squeezed, if there weren't space(s) at either of sides near `values` - they will be added)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape your parentheses with a `\` as those are control characters in regex.

That being said while I usually use awk like the hammer that it is, I feel like `sed` is more appropriate here:

```
sed s/\)values\(/\)\ values\ \(/g sso-shop-med.txt
```

Comment: No you dont have to escape parens, quite the opposite. Escaping them turns them into capture group delimiters - just leave them alone and they'll be treated literally. Remember - sed uses BREs, not EREs. Also, never leave a script unquoted, the correct sed syntax would be `sed 's/)values(/) values (/g' sso-shop-med.txt`

Comment: what is BRE and ERE?

Comment: @JNevill when to use awk and when to use sed? Is there any rule for that?

Comment: awk is good for processing a file line by line (record by record) and dealing with each field in the record. I think of awk more like a simple database query like `SELECT substring(field2 FROM 1 FOR 4)  FROM <file> WHERE <field1>="somevalue"` where `sed` is a "Stream editor" so it just gobbles down the file like a stream looking for a regex hit and performing changes as it gobbles the file. Also, apparently I totally botched this answer (although it works by accident) so take this answer with a grain of salt. Ed's comment explains (that man knows his sed and really knows awk).

Comment: yeah true, Thnx for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl in UNIX, this can be solved.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
while(<>){
print if(s/\((values)\)/\ $1 \/);
}
```

The output:

```
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204026601',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502683504',18, TRUE, current_date,'502675409',current_date,'502675409'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009239', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704'); 
insert into brs.user_shops (user_name, shop_id, is_active, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('204009292', 18, TRUE, current_date, '212585704', current_date, '212585704');
```